# Treat the missing values (conditional Imputation ) Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation, missing-data

I have a block in the processing of missing data

i have this df

```py
index                   a          b     c      del 
2018-06-25 12:51:00    NaN        NaN   NaN      1
2018-06-25 12:52:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     NaN
2018-06-25 12:53:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     NaN 
2018-06-25 12:54:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     NaN 
2018-06-25 12:55:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     NaN
2018-06-25 12:56:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     NaN 
2018-06-25 12:57:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     NaN 
2018-06-25 12:58:00    0.5        0.6   0.6     0.0
2018-06-25 12:59:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0.0
2018-06-25 13:00:00    0.6        0.8   0.6     0.0
2018-06-25 13:01:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0.0 
2018-06-25 13:02:00    0.6        0.9   0.6     0.0
```

what I want to do

interpolate missing values if the value of `del` is not missing

i have this solution keep just the df when del has a value and I do my interpolation after I concatene

but I want to avoid concatenation and too much line of code and variables

```
dfs= df.loc[df['del'].notnull(),:]
dfs.interpolate(method='time')

dfs1= df.loc[df['del'].isnull(),:]

dfs= pd.concat([dfs,dfs1], axis=1, sort=True,  join_axes=[df.index])
```

desired output :

```py
index                   a          b     c        del 
2018-06-25 12:51:00    NaN        NaN   NaN       1.0
2018-06-25 12:52:00    NaN        NaN   NaN       NaN
2018-06-25 12:53:00    NaN        NaN   NaN       NaN 
2018-06-25 12:54:00    NaN        NaN   NaN       NaN 
2018-06-25 12:55:00    NaN        NaN   NaN       NaN
2018-06-25 12:56:00    NaN        NaN   NaN       NaN 
2018-06-25 12:57:00    NaN        NaN   NaN       NaN 
2018-06-25 12:58:00    0.5        0.6   0.6       0.0
2018-06-25 12:59:00    0.6        0.7   0.7       0.0
2018-06-25 13:00:00    0.6        0.8   0.6       0.0
2018-06-25 13:01:00    0.7        0.9   0.7       0.0 
2018-06-25 13:02:00    0.6        0.9   0.6       0.0
```

story of just closing the little hole by column

Thank you <<

Comment: Some of the values in your output seem to be off. You get 0.7 interpolating between two values of 0.6.

Comment: it's just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.loc` to assign the interpolation only where `'del'` is not null:

```
df.loc[df['del'].notnull()] = df.loc[df['del'].notnull()].interpolate(method='time')

                        a     b    c  del
2018-06-25 12:51:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  1.0
2018-06-25 12:52:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2018-06-25 12:53:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2018-06-25 12:54:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2018-06-25 12:55:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2018-06-25 12:56:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2018-06-25 12:57:00   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2018-06-25 12:58:00  0.50  0.60  0.6  0.0
2018-06-25 12:59:00  0.55  0.70  0.6  0.0
2018-06-25 13:00:00  0.60  0.80  0.6  0.0
2018-06-25 13:01:00  0.60  0.85  0.6  0.0
2018-06-25 13:02:00  0.60  0.90  0.6  0.0
```

Comment: I will try this